# Python interpreter and pip give different versions of module

Tags: python, scipy, pip

I have encountered some issues a long time ago with python and pip and I don't remember what exactly. Now this bothers me: `python3 -m pip show scipy` returns `Version: 0.17.1` but when I launch a Python interpreter with `python3` and `import scipy`, `scipy.__version__` returns `0.13.3`. And obviously when I run some script I have this version-related issue:

```
ImportError: No module named 'scipy.lib.decorator'
```

What can I do? Many thanks,

Comment: Indeed, I should have stated it: I already tried python3 -m pip install --upgrade scipy, didn't change anything since the version seen by scipy is already the latest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like have two versions of `scipy` installed, and `sys.path` is finding the older version first. In a Python3 interpreter type:

```
>>> import scipy
>>> scipy.__version__
'0.18.0.dev0+4a89f2d'
>>> scipy.__file__
'/home/unutbu/.virtualenvs/muffy/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py'
```

The last line shows the directory where the loaded scipy package was found. 
Above, the directory is

```
/home/unutbu/.virtualenvs/muffy/lib/python3.4/site-packages/
```

Check the equivalent directory on your machine for both the 0.13 and 0.17 versions of scipy. If you are satisfied that both exist, and you don't need the 0.13 version of the scipy directory, go ahead and remove it. If the 0.13 version was installed by a package manager, be sure to remove it using the same package manager so that the package manager will remain up-to-date with the state of the system.

Comment: Did the trick, thanks! I had a version in `/usr/lib/python3.4/` and the pip version in `/usr/local/lib/dist-packages/`. I deleted the first one and everything worked.

Comment: Oops! I had mistakenly assumed both versions were manually installed.
If the scipy version in `/usr/lib` was installed by a package manager (such as `apt-get` or `yum`), you should use the package manager to remove the package that installed `scipy` in `/usr/lib`. For example, use `sudo apt-get remove python3-scipy` on Ubuntu. This will keep the package manager up to date with the state of its packages.